# kendo ui numeric column editor value resets on record add

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to add a numeric spinner input box to a column in a Kendo UI grid.

For some reason if I 'add' a record to the `dataSource` and change the numeric value, then 'add' another row, the value in all the previously added rows gets set to 1?

```
    $("#add-btn").click(function(){

      $("#items-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.add({NAME:"Apples",QTY:1})

    })

    $("#items-grid").kendoGrid({
        height: 300,
        columns : [
            {
                field : "NAME",
                title : "Name"
            },
            {
                field : "QTY",
                title : "Qty",
                width: 140 ,
                template: "<input class='numeric' value='#: QTY #' style='width:100%'> </input>"
            }   ],
            noRecords: true, 
            dataSource: [] ,
            dataBound: function() {
                this.tbody.find(".numeric").each(function(){
                    $(this).kendoNumericTextBox({decimals: 0});
                });
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ow4sj3b/

Please advise

Comment: I can't get the fiddle to work, there is no error but the grid does not renders, the result section stays white. Anyway, I would suggest you to use [`editor`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editor) option in that case, instead of creating the widget in the `dataBound` event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my Kendo Grid was that I hadn't added a `model` to the `schema` to specify the "number" type for the `QTY` column.

Without this, the inline `numericTextBox` doesn't behave correctly

```
dataSource : new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [],
            schema: {
                model: {
                  fields: {
                     QTY: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} }
                  }
                }
            }
         }),
```